# Get some information from HEVC reference software

Tags: video-encoding, hevc

I am new to HEVC and I am understanding the reference software now (looking at intra prediction right now).

I need to get information as below after encoding.

- the CU structure for a given CTU
- for each CU during calculations, it's information (eg. QP value, selected mode for Luma, selected mode for chroma, whether the CU is in final CU structure of the CTU-split decision, etc.)

I know CTU decision are made when `m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu )` is called in `TEncSlice.cpp`. But where exactly I can get these specific information? Can someone help me with this?

p.s. I am learning C++ too (I have a Java background).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: This post is a solution for the encoder side. However, the decoder side solution is far less complex.

Getting CTU information (partitioning etc.) is a bit tricky at encoder if you are new to the code. But I try to help you with it. 
Everything that I am going to tell you is based on the JEM code and not HM, but I am pretty sure that you can apply them to HM too.

As you might have noticed, there are two completely separate phases for compression/encoding of each CTU:

1. The RDO phase: first there is the Rate-Distortion Optimization loop to "make the decisions". In this phase, literally all possible combinations of the parameters are tested (e.g. differetn partitionings, intra modes, filters etc.). At the end of this phase the RDO determines the best combination and passes them to the second phase.
2. The encoding phase: Here the encoder does the actual final encoding step. This includes writing all the bins into the bitstream, based on the parameters determined during the RDO phase.

In the CTU level, these two phases are performed by the `m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu )` and the `m_pcCuEncoder->encodeCtu( pCtu )` functions, respectively, both in the `compressSlice()` function of the `TEncSlice.cpp` file.

Given the above information, you must look for what you are looking for, in the **second phase** and not the **first phase** (you may already know these things, but I suspected that you might be looking at the first phase).

So, now this is my suggestion for getting your information. It's not the best way to do it, but is easier to explain here. 
You first go to this point in your HM code:

`compressGOP() -> encodeSlice() -> encodeCtu() -> xEncodeCU()`

Then you find the line where the prediction mode (intra/inter) is encoded:

`m_pcEntropyCoder->encodePredMode()`

At this point, you have access to the `pcCU` object which contains all the final decisions, including the information you look for, that are made during the first phase. At this point of the code, you are dealing with a single CU and not the entire CTU. But if you want your information for the entire CTU, you may go back to

`compressGOP() -> encodeSlice() -> encodeCtu()`

and find the line where the `xEncodeCU()` function is called for the first time. There, you will have access to the `pCtu` object.

**Reminder:** each `TComDataCU` object (`pcCU` if you are in the CU level, or `pCtu` if you are in the CTU level) of size `WxH` is split to `NumPartition=(W/4)x(H/4)` partitions of size `4x4`. Each partition is accessible by an index (`uiAbsPartIdx`) which indicates its Z-scan order. For example, the `uiAbsPartIdx` for the partition at `<x=8,y=0>` is 4.

Now, you do the following steps:

1. Get the number of partitions (`NumPartition`) within your `pCtu` by calling `pCtu->getTotalNumPart()`.
2. Loop over all `NumPartition` partitions and call the functions `pCtu->getWidth(idx)`, `pCtu->getHeight(idx)`, `pCtu->getCUPelX(idx)` and `pCtu->getCUPelY()`, where `idx` is your loop iterator. These functions return the following information for each `CU` coincided with the `4x4` partition at `idx`: width, height, positionX, positionY. [both positions are relative to the pixel `<0,0>` of the frame]
3. The above information is enough for deriving the CTU partitioning of the current `pCtu`! So the last step is to write a piece of code to do that.

This was an example of how to extract CTU partitioning information during the second phase (i.e. encoding phase). However, you may call some proper functions to get the other information in your second question. For example, to get selected luma intra mode, you may call `pCtu->getIntraDir(CHANNEL_TYPE_LUMA, idx)`, instead of `getWidth()/getHeight()` functions. Or `pCtu->getQP(CHANNEL_TYPE_LUMA, idx)` to get the QP value.

You can always find a list of functions that provide useful information at the `pCtu` level, in the `TComDataCU` class (`TComDataCU.cpp`).

I hope this helps you. If not, let me know!

Good luck,

Comment: Thanks a lot for all information! I am new to HEVC and each piece of information you have put down is very valuable to me. I have some questions. 
1. All times I call `pCtu->getTotalNumPart()` in `TencSlice.cpp` after `m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu )`, I get 256. Even when `*(pCtu->getWidth())` returns 32, I get 256. Why is this? For 32, shouldn't this be 64?
2. In `pCtu->getIntraDir(CHANNEL_TYPE_LUMA, idx)`, do you mean `uiAbsPartIdx` by `idx`?
I am new to HEVC and I am thankful for your time. Also is there are code trace guide anywhere that I can have a look other than official one?

Comment: 1. It makes sense. Because `pCtu` is actually your `64x64` CTU and when you call '`getTotalNumPart()` on it, you should get `(64/4)x(64/4)=16x16=256` partitions. 
Remember that a CTU is [almost] always in the size of `64x64`. It's CU that can have smaller sizes e.g. 32. If you want to call `getTotalNumPart()` on a specific CU inside your CTU, then you'll have to go to the other address that I said (inside '`xEncodeCU()` function)

Comment: 2. Yes. The `idx` actually acts as `uiAbsPartIdx`. But I wanted to emphasis that you should **iterate** over different `uiAbsPartIdx` values to scan all `4x4` partitions inside each CTU (CU). 

3. Regarding your last question, unfortunately, there is no manual or code trace sample that I'm aware of. You have to learn by digging it and asking questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Very helpful. I will go through the code and I might have more questions and I will ask them in new questions.

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway to know when a full scan line is encoded and the encoder is just to begin encoding of the next line ? I am using HM software but it would be appreciated any help from other encoders too !

Comment: Maverick, you may ask it in another question.

Comment: At the 1st RDO phase, beside the information (decisions) stored inside the CU and CTUs structures are they any other structures ie pppcRDSbacCoder that keeps informations for the 2nd phase ? I mean  the 2nd phase (encoding) is using exclusively the results from CU and CTUs structures or other external settings are also matters ?

Comment: No. Nothing except the decisions. CABAC is reset in the beginnig of the encosing phase and all its status is initialized.