# Extract TU Partitioning Information in HEVC Reference Software 16.18

Tags: transform, block, partitioning, hevc

I want to extract CU/PU/TU partitioning data from HEVC HM encoder. 
I could extract CU/PU partitioning information using getHeight/getWidth/getPartitionSize functions in TComDataCU class. But, don't know how to access TU partitioning information. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily on the decoder side. 
You need to find the function `parseCoeffNxN` and then access the TU size with `uiWidth` and `uiHeight`.

Start with this simple test and then give feedbacks here. If there's a problem, we will figure out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, currently, I want to extract the information from the encoder side. After compressSlice, I could extract CU size using pcPic->getCtu(nextCtuTsAddr)->getHeight(curCUAddr) (loop over all CTUs and all 4x4 blocks in each CTU); I guess I can extract TU size in a similar manner. But, I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 0):

On the encoder side, you should do the same thing as the decoder side, but in the `codeCoeffNxN` function instead of `parseCoeffNxN`. The only difficulty is that you should differentiate between the times you call this function during RDO and encoding. This problem and its solution are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749824/4643483).