# Extract co located CTU information in HM HEVC

Tags: hevc

How we can extract information of co located CTU in HM software?
I need CTU partitioning information of co located CTU when I encode current CTU.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be during encoding? Because it is easier while decoding.

Comment: Yes, I am doing research on it. I am on high demand to know how to access to CTU information in the reference frames especially last frame. As far as I see the reference frames, CTUs informations have been cleared after encoding each frame.

Comment: Check this out then: [Extract TU Partitioning Information in HEVC Reference Software 16.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395870/extract-tu-partitioning-information-in-hevc-reference-software-16-18/51416999#51416999)